Video MP4 does not work in the mobile version of the site
I have an animation saved as MP4 video file and it does not work in the mobile version of the site, although through the element explorer in the smartphone browser, everything is fine.
On the phone, the video just turns off and that's it, although it should increase and stand in the center of the screen when you click on the screensaver (poster image).
I tried using JS, but video is not showing.
My HTML code:
<div class="bakctage">                                  
<div class="video__poster" tabindex="0">                                              
<video id="video" class="video" poster="assets/img/постеры к                
 подкастам/IMG_8742.JPG"src="assets/video/сладко.mp4" tabindex="0"></video>                                 <a href="#video" id="play__img" class="video__img"></a>                             
</div>                             
<div class="bakctage-info">                                 
<a>Фриц Ланг - М</a>                             
</div>                             
<div class="backstage_data">                                    
<a>Дата:</a> <a>29.06.2020</a>                              
</div>                          
</div>

CSS
.video__poster video {
        width: 230px;
        height: 140px;
    }
.video__poster video {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5%;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
    .video__poster[tabindex="0"] {
    cursor: zoom-in;
    }
    
    .video__poster video[tabindex="0"]:focus {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 90;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 90%;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 90%;
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 0 0 200px #000, 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 200px #000, 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 200px #000, 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }

    .video__poster video[tabindex="0"]:focus,
    .video__poster video[tabindex="0"]:focus~* {
    cursor: pointer;  
    }

JS
<script>
    const videos = document.querySelectorAll('.video');
    videos.forEach(video => {
        const playButton = video.parentElement.querySelector('.video__img');
        playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (video.paused) {
                videos.forEach(otherVideo => {
                    if (otherVideo !== video && !otherVideo.paused) {
                        otherVideo.pause();
                        otherVideo.parentElement.querySelector('.video__img').classList.remove('play__img-off');
                        otherVideo.removeAttribute("controls");
                    }
                });

                video.play();
                playButton.textContent = '';
                playButton.classList.add('play__img-off');
                video.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
            } else {
                video.pause();
                playButton.textContent = '';
                playButton.classList.remove('play__img-off');
                video.removeAttribute("controls");
            }
        });
    });
</script>


In your code where you defined  element it was missing video playing attribute.
Poster property was set for the video so by default when you open website on mobile then the poster will be shown instead of video being played so you have to add property like
<video
      id="video"
      class="video"
      autoplay
      poster="assets/img/sample.jpeg"
      src="assets/videos/sample.mp4"
      tabindex="0"
    >
    </video>

The autoplay attribute plays the video instantly when the page is loaded.
For you to make sure video always keep on playing without stopping you can do so by specifying loop attribute as well
<video
      id="video"
      class="video"
      autoplay
      loop
      poster="assets/img/sample.jpeg"
      src="assets/videos/sample.mp4"
      tabindex="0"
    >
    </video>


Adding a muted in the <video> setup might help with autoplay. Mobile browsers do not allow videos to autoplay with sound. The user must first click/tap to play.
